# jQuery show div when the user has scrolled up to the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div style="height:0px;" class="mytopdiv">Text</div>
  <div class="header">OtherContent</div>
  <div class="page">PageContent</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I need to show .mytopdiv when the user has scrolled up to the header.
i've tried this way:

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
     if ($('.mytopdiv').height() < 340) {
       scrolldiff = $(window).scrollTop();
       if (scrolldiff < 0) {
        height = $('.mytopdiv').height() + Math.abs(scrolldiff);
        $('.mytopdiv').height(height);
       }
     }
    });
```

But it works only on chrome and safari and doesn't work on touch devices and firefox.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "scrolled up to the header" ? can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

well you can say its a kind of bug..try below thing

```
if($.browser.safari) bodyElement = $("body")
else bodyElement = $("html,body")

bodyElement.scrollTop(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar effect and I use to compare:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 2) { ... }
```

The "2" if for avoid situations where the scroll is "almost" on top but not totally.

But I use opacity attribute, I think that the effect is more friendly using css animations.